# Pulling down a website built with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So for my current job function, I pull down client websites- visit site via Chrome, go to 'file > save page as' and then relink assets. Then I use this local version of their website and incorporate our data using php and they link to us as if we were simply a page of their site. It's meant to be a seamless experience and exact design match. I just pulled down a website that is outrageously broken locally and it seems that the issue is that the site is built with AngularJS. Is it possible to pull an AngularJS site off the web like this and have all of the files I need? Anyone know anything at all about what I'm looking at? Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of times there are hidden .js files not referenced. You can get it to work locally, but you'll need to view sources and ensure every last file is pulled. It's also worth noting that AngularJS and Angular both are built to prevent content stealing and reuse, and make things like this difficult for clients w/o source code.

Comment: @Z.Bagley I strongly disagree that [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is built to prevent content stealing and reuse, do you have evidence of this?

Comment: The encrypted minified bundling for starts....